# Oracle SQL Developer - Create View with parameters

Tags: sql, oracle, view

I'm new to Oracle SQL and I'm currently working on an Oracle SQL view in Oracle SQL Developer.

I need two parameters in my View

- fruitType (string)
- fruitNumber (int)

I tried the following (simplified) statement in Oracle SQL Developer:

```
CREATE VIEW FRUITSRESULT (fruitType, fruitNumber) AS
SELECT
   fruit_col1 as FruitType,
   fruit_col2 as FruitNumber
   fruit_col3 as FruitInfo
FROM
   FRUITGARDEN
WHERE
   fruit_col1 = fruitType
   fruit_col2 = fruitNumber
;
```

Unfortunately this does not work, I always get the following error:

```
Error starting at line : 1 in command - 
...

ORA-00904: "FRUITNUMBER": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Do you know how to solve this error?

Is it actually possible to create a parameterized View in Oracle SQL?

Comment: Your current query can be easily used with regular view and `where` clause on top of it, because predicates are pushed into view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it actually possible to create a parameterized View in Oracle SQL?

No, that is not possible.

What you are thinking of as parameters are the column aliases for the output:

```sql
CREATE VIEW FRUITSRESULT (fruitType, fruitNumber, FruitInfo) AS
SELECT fruit_col1,
       fruit_col2,
       fruit_col3
FROM   FRUITGARDEN;
```

Will output the values `fruit_col1`, `fruit_col2` and `fruit_col3` with the columns aliased to `fruitType`, `fruitNumber`, and `FruitInfo` (respectively). They are not, as you assumed, input parameters.